# How to get publishingcredentials using Azure CLI for newly created/updated appservice using ARM template

Tags: java, azure, ftp, azure-cli

I am trying to automate process of creating a Java appservice using ARM template and then utilize FTP publishing method to upload Java WAR file for Tomcat.

Following does not work in Azure CLI -

```
$ azure resource show <resource-group> <appservice-name>/publishingcredentials Microsoft.Web/sites/config 2015-08-01

error:   The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web' for api version '2015-08-01'
```

But this works in Azure PowerShell -

```
$resource = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <resource-group> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName <appservice-name>/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$resource.Properties
```

I have been referring to namespaces from Resource Explorer https://resources.azure.com but not able to find the right syntax to get FTP username and password that I can use later in the script to upload WAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative.

If resource group was created manually and FTP Publishing Credentials for any website under the resource group was setup manually. Then this will setup an alternate FTP credential for the resource group - not specific to any website (or may be it is global for the whole account).

Each website once created sets up a different domain on FTP server and the alternate credential works for any website -  ftp:///username@waws-prod-sn1-033.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net.

Now from Jenkin, if we create a new siteName based on git branch name under same resource group, we can use the above pre-configured FTP credential for the new siteName as well to upload the application archive.

I wish there was a way to retrieve at least the alternate credentials using Azure CLI. Resource explorer shows it under - https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Web/publishingUsers/web?api-version=2015-08-01.

Or even if "siteConfig" properties under ARM template can be setup to configure publishingUsername and publishingPassword. I tried this option but these properties get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure CLI `azure resource show` is similar to Azure PowerShell `Get-AzureRmResource`, and it's always using the "GET" method. If you add "-vv" option, you will see the REST API it's using. On the other hand, the PowerShell `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` is using the "POST" method. if you add '-debug' option to `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` you would be able to see the REST API.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<your subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<app service>/config/publishingcredentials/list?api-version=2015-08-01
```

Here is a PowerShell script to invoke this REST API:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'

# The tenant ID of you Subscription. You can use tenant name instead.
$tenantID = "<the tenant ID of your Subscription>"

# You can leave the variables as what they are, if you are under Azure Cloud Environment.
$loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/"
$managementResourceURI = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
$redirectURI = New-Object System.Uri ("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
$clientID = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"

# Fill in the below variables.
$subscriptionID = "<your subscription id>"
$resouceGroup = "<your resource group>"
$appService = "<your app service>"
$username = "<your Azure account>"


# Constructing the authentication string.
$authString = $loginEndpoint + $tenantID

# Use the above authentication string to create an authentication context.
$authenticationContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ($authString, $false)

$promptBehaviour = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto

$userIdentifierType = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType]::RequiredDisplayableId

$userIdentifier = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier ($username, $userIdentifierType)


# Prompt for signing in.
$authenticationResult = $authenticationContext.AcquireToken($managementResourceURI, $clientID, $redirectURI, $promptBehaviour, $userIdentifier); 

# construct authorization header for the REST API.
$authHeader = $authenticationResult.AccessTokenType + " " + $authenticationResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

# Invoke the REST API.
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$appService/config/publishingcredentials/list?api-version=2015-08-01" `
                  -Headers $headers
```

If you are under Linux System, you can use curl with OAuth 2. The below bash script will give you the publishing credential of your web app. But, In order to use my script, you need to [create a service principle](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/) and [install curl in you Linux system](https://linuxmoz.com/ubuntu-install-curl-command/).

```
#!/bin/bash

tenantID="<the tenant id of your subscription>"

client_id="<the client id of your AD application>"

client_secret="<a key you added to your AD application>"

body="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F"

authorization=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-ascii "$body" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/token" | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print(obj["token_type"]+" "+obj["access_token"])')


subscriptionID="<your subscription id>"
resourceGroup="<the resource group of you web app>"
appService="<your web app>"

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: $authorization" --data-ascii "" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$appService/config/publishingcredentials/list?api-version=2015-08-01"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a detailed example of using REST API to get publishingcredentials. I could definitely use this example in some other context. Until Azure CLI is fixed to support level 2 resources, I guess I will have to use Windows machine for Jenkin server and use Azure PowerShell.

Comment: I have check the Azure CLI, they actually do support Level 2 resources with `--parent` option. However, it dose not help for you case, because `azure resource show` is always using "GET" method, while in your case, you need to use "POST" method. I will update my answer a little bit.